# Get current entry field from inside a macro

Tags: entry

**Scenario**:

I am creating a twig macro to display a navigation menu.

Said menu will be displayed on any page (home, blog, multiple landing pages, ...)

In some cases we will be visiting a specific entry of a section (for example in the blog).

**What I want:**

I want to be able to access a specific field of the current entry if it is defined.

For example, access blog section specialField.

**What I am trying:**

I am trying to access it with `entry.specialField`

**The problem:**

`entry.specialField` is not defined when I am in the macro (even if I am visiting an entry that has the specialField).

**The question:**

How can I access this, inside the macro?

**For people who have used WordPress:**

This would be equivalent to something like getting a *meta value* from the current *post*. It can be achieved easily with `global $post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the entry module (or just parts of the entry module, e.g. entry.title) as a parameter when calling the macro in your template.

Macro:

```
{% macro drawEntryTitle(entry) %}
  <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
{% endmacro %}
```

Call macro:

```
{{ macro.drawEntryTitle(entry) }}
```